# How to configure Tiger security scanner

Tags: ids

I'm running an Arch linux machine and want to run a scan using this tool called Tiger. I saw [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Oz9aBVvoYY) where the guy teaches to install it and run. In the video it ran normally after installed. In my case, when I run it gives me the message:

> --ERROR-- [init002e] No 'config' file in `.'.

How to setup it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error message is quite clear - did you create a configuration file? And is it in the current directory?

Comment: well, of course, but what is the point in creating an empty config file? I don't know how to fill the file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda solved the problem by reinstalling it from its repository instead of using arch linux package manager. First I uninstalled it then

> git clone git://git.savannah.gnu.org/tiger.git
>
> ./configure
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

Then it created all the necessary files to run.